# Servidor Mysql en localhost no funciona

Tags: mysql, mysql-sever

He intentado instalar un servidor de mysql en mi máquina local pero no consigo que funcione.

Me he descargado el zip desde aquí: https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/

Después he seguido estos pasos: http://webdevzoom.com/install-mysql-zip-file-on-windows/

Pero me da el siguiente error:

> ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10061)

He buscado el error pero las soluciones que dan en esos sitios a mi no me ha servido.

Al ejecutar `mysqld --console` me sale lo siguiente:

> 2018-07-27T13:54:56.349166Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] c:\mysql-5.7.17\bin\mysqld.exe (mysqld 8.0.11) starting as process 5764
>
> 2018-07-27T13:54:56.373933Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-011011] [Server] Failed to find valid data directory.
>
> 2018-07-27T13:54:56.376442Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010020] [Server] Data Dictionary initialization failed.
>
> 2018-07-27T13:54:56.379069Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
>
> 2018-07-27T13:54:56.382633Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] c:\mysql-5.7.17\bin\mysqld.exe: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.11)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.

Contenido del ini

```
[mysqld]

basedir = "/mysql-5.7.17"
datadir = "/mysql-5.7.17/data"
tmpdir = "/mysql-5.7.17/tmp"
port = 3306
server_id = 1
log_error = "mysql_error.log"
pid_file = "mysql.pid"
socket = "/mysql-5.7.17/mysql.sock"

# Optional - Default Configuration
max_allowed_packet = 8M
key_buffer_size=16M

# Where do all the plugins live
plugin_dir = "/mysql-5.7.17/lib/plugin/"
```

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80924/discussion-on-question-by-pavlo-b-servidor-mysql-en-localhost-no-funciona).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hola Pavlo estuve haciendo pruebas en mi computadora (también con windows 10) y creo que el problema esta en las rutas, en mi caso tengo instalado en la raíz del disco c, las rutas me quedan por ejemplo `basedir = "c:/mysql-5.7.17"` si lo cambio y solo dejo la / en todas las configuraciones al igual que a ti no inicia el servidor.

Por lo general suelo usar el instalador porque este te crea los servicios y tal, por mi parte te recomendaría probarlo.

Comment: Al final opté por el instalador, pero el problema que tengo ahora es que no sé como conectarme a la bd desde mi proyecto en symfony, ya que me está diciendo que no existe el driver...

Comment: encontre esta otra pregunta que es tu problema actual https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36247203/symfony-3-mysql-driver-could-not-find-driver">Symfony 3 MySQL driver 'could not find driver'

Comment: en esa pregunta el usa una maquina virtual como servidor de mysql pero yo quiero usarlo en local

Answer (score 0):

Al final el problema era que en el archivo de php.ini del php, no la del proyecto de symfony, el pdo_mysql no estaba activado y por eso symfony no detectaba el driver.

Comment: Pavlo entonces la otra respuesta no es la correcta?

Comment: No es que no sea correcta, es que no es el problema que yo tengo,

Comment: Entonces porque la marcaste como correcta? Si tienes una respuesta correcta, tal vez no sera atractivo dar una recompensa. Una respuesta debe cumplir lo mencionado en [answer].

Comment: Por que en parte si que es la respuesta que necesitaba pes lo instalé con el instalador, por otra parte lo otro era una tontería por el tema de habilitar el mysql en el php.ini del php que tengo instalado.